# Runtime port generation in grails framework

Tags: url, grails, hosting, port, web-hosting

I am using grails framework to develop a web application. I need to generate the runtime server URL as follows: `http:hostname:port/application/`. In grails configuration we have an option to provide the serverURL using `grails.serverURL`.

My question is: **Can we get the port number of server which the application is running at runtime? Is this possible?**

Comment: Grails already create the correct links to your, so I'm guessing that this is not your problem. For what do you need the port?

Comment: i need the port to numbers to run the application in different environments,In my case  only 8080 port for Development and 80 and 443(SSL) is for production.if i can get the port number of the server that is currently using then i can form the URL with that port and form the URL

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
System.getProperty("server.port", "8080")
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

If you have different profiles(config blocks) per environment, you can likely set the **grails.server.port.http** property in there.